# not able to import Account object using 'JSON Dataflow'

Tags: einstein-analytics

I am getting following error with ‘JSON Dataflow’.

*“There was an error executing the Extract_account node: Fields `[name, account_legal_name__c]` are not available. Verify that the fields exists and that the Analytics Cloud Integration User profile has Read level access on the fields. `(02K290000000CqsEAE_03C290000008qdVEAQ)`”*

JSON File excerpt:

```
"Extract_account": {
    "action": "sfdcDigest",
    "parameters": {
        "object": "account",
        "fields": [
          {"name": "Id"},
          {"name": "Account_CSN__c"},
          {"name": "name"},
          {"name": "account_legal_name__c"}
          ]
    }
}
```

I have checked the Integration User profile multiple times and am pretty sure, it has read and even edit access to `name` & `account_legal_name__c` field. At the same time, “`Account_CSN__c` is another custom field and works fine.

Am I missing something for granting Read access on name field?

Comment: When you say read and edit access ,Are you saying you have right FLS  as Integration User Profile?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I gave Edit access to make it work, though, eventually in Production this profile will not have Edit access. Based on error message it is clear that this is access issue, but where? Is there any other way to test this access issue. I can not even create a user & login with 'custom Analytics Cloud Integration User' profile.

Answer (score 0):

as I cannot comment I am writing the answer.
There is bug or issue with this I to have encountered it.
a workaround is you make a new data flow from scratch after providing necessary permissions in profile and it will work.Worked for me